# How to populate Json String into Android spinner

Tags: android, json, dictionary, spinner

My `Json` response is not an array. It is a single `Json` object (That has dynamic Keys and values pairs as below):

```
{
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2",
    "key3": "value3",
    "key4": "value4",
    "key5": "value5",
    "key6": "value6",
    "key7": "value7",
    "key8": "value8",
}
```

How to populate values into Android spinner or How to create a Map from this `Json` response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the solution. For the response type I did not use JsonObject. I used `HashMap<String, String>`

```
     @GET("api")
 fun getListItems(
         @Header(NetworkUtils.CONTENT_TYPE) contentType: String = NetworkUtils.CONTENT_TYPE_PARAMS,
         @Header(NetworkUtils.AUTHORIZATION) bearerToken: String,
         @Query("language") language: String?
): Observable<Response<HashMap<String, String>>>
```

Then just use the HashMap on the Spinner

```
override fun populatesCaseTypesSpinner(response: HashMap<String, String>) {
     val adapter = ArrayAdapter(context!!, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, ArrayList(response.keys))

     adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)

     spinnerCaseTypes.adapter = adapter

     spinnerCaseTypes.setOnTouchListener(View.OnTouchListener { _, _ ->
         hideKeyboard()
         false
     })
```

}

Answer (score 1):

```
JsonObject json = new JsonObject(<yourresponse>);
```

**Solution**

```
    Iterator<String> keys = json.keys();
    List<String> valueList = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> keyList = new ArrayList<String>();
    while( keys.hasNext() ){
        String key = (String)keys.next();
        String value = jObject.getString(key); 
        valueList.add(value);
        keyList.add(key);
    }
```

Pass either key list or value list to ArrayAdapter of the Spinner

Comment: Thank you for the reply but How can i create the map from the Json response? That is the part I can not figure out

Comment: is this part of an API call result ?

Comment: yes. the one that I sent is the API Response

{
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2",
    "key3": "value3",
    "key4": "value4",
    "key5": "value5",
    "key6": "value6",
    "key7": "value7",
    "key8": "value8",
}

Answer (score 1):

The entire JSON response can be read as a `JSONObject` that you can iterate through its elements and get String data into a List.

```
    String jsonResponse = "{\n" +
            "    \"key1\": \"value1\",\n" +
            "    \"key2\": \"value2\",\n" +
            "    \"key3\": \"value3\",\n" +
            "    \"key4\": \"value4\",\n" +
            "    \"key5\": \"value5\",\n" +
            "    \"key6\": \"value6\",\n" +
            "    \"key7\": \"value7\",\n" +
            "    \"key8\": \"value8\"\n" +
            "}";

    ArrayList<String> spinnerList = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        JSONObject root = new JSONObject(jsonResponse);

        for (int i = 1; i <= root.length(); i++) {
            String value = root.getString("key" + i);
            spinnerList.add(value);
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    Spinner spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, spinnerList);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```